# How to check the colour of the text on a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, textcolor

Sounds simple, right? Well I've Googled over a dozen search strings and still cannot find the answer.

To set the colour we implement the following code:

```
[_myUIButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But what about testing to see what the colour is of the text of the button??? Surely this is possible to do, right?

Shouldn't the code be something like this:

```
if([_myUIButton.textColor isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]])
{
    // then true
}
```

This code won't work with the button title text colour, but someone must know how it can be done.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to check color? Don't you set the color based on states? Why don't you check the states instead of the color? You probably haven't found anything because there isn't a need to check the color of the text...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if([button titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor blackColor]]){

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, check the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleColorForState%3a).

```
- (UIColor *)titleColorForState:(UIControlState)state;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIButton's currentTitleColor property:

```
if ([button.currentTitleColor isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]]) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"Color is %@",[btn currentTitleColor]); this will give you the answer 0 0 0 1 for black color it means red is 0 green is 0 and blue is 0 and alpha is 1,this way you find the RGB of  any color ,alternatively you can use if condition to match a specific color

Answer (score 0):

you also can use

```
if([myButton.titleLabel.textColor  isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]]){
    // your code
}
```